# Why is my post Community Wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

[My post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376789/how-to-use-the-function-type-in-scala-within-defined-in-type-meaningfully) suddenly converted to Community Wiki yesterday when I edited it. I don't remember telling it to switch; did I change it by mistake?

Comment: Editing to add more information isn't that a bad thing. If you wish, flag for moderator attention (click the "flag" link under the "scala" tags), choose "it needs ♦ moderator attention" > "Other" and in the box request for un-wikifying.

Comment: okay thanks! I feel odd that my answer to my question also becomes wiki due to too much editing...

Comment: @ClarkBao Regular posts aren't meant to be edited that often, unlike a wiki.  If the content is changing that often then it's only fair to turn it into a wiki, to facilitate collaborative editing and prevent abuse.

Comment: @Matthrw Read, perhaps there should be a warning when user edit the post too much, otherwise we are just not aware of it.

Comment: @irrationalJohn You can flag for a mod to un-CW it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably down to the fact you post was edited 13 times. If a posted is edited 10 times (or more) by it's original owner it is forced into Community Wiki.

For more information, please see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: I didn't know this rule... I just find something I need to edit,then I keep on editing it... a bit sad....